# Duplicate data when using PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-service, android-pendingintent, google-fit, android-fusedlocation

I am listening to `DetectedActivity`, `FusedLocation`, `GoogleFit` etc. updates using a `pending intent`. I pass over

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT when calling: pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 12, intentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

However, I still get duplicate data.

I tried using a different request id for every time I listen to certain updates (different request id for listening to FusedLocation updates, different request id for listening to GoogleFit updates etc.) but it still gives me duplicate data. I also tried adding different actionIds to the intentService

Inside my Service, I have the following code:

```
intentService = new Intent(this, SensorsIntentService.class); //in onCreate
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 12, intentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

I expect only one set of data every time and no duplicates.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, answering my own question, apparently my problem was not about the pending intent flag, but about the `onStartCommand`
 inside my `service`. Apparently it was called twice (second time because of me moving the `service` to the `foreground` by calling:

```
startForeground(id, notification)
```

(correct me if I am wrong regards to the reason) so the listeners were registering again and so data was being sent twice. Instead of starting this in the `onStartCommand` I now start the `foregroundService` in the `onBind`.

The only thing I didn't figure out is: I had to create a `BroadcastReceiver` instead of my `IntentService` to handle the `pendingIntent` and in my `Service` implementation I now use

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12, intentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

instead of

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 12, intentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

or else the `pendingIntent` is never caught.
Anyone have an idea why?